# how to change search icon white to black on white background jquery mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, icons, themeroller

I am working in jquery mobile i need to change white icon on search input to black.

here is my code

```
<div id="dvSearch" data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label" >
    <label id="lblSearch" for="txtsearch">Search</label>
    <input type="search" id="txtsearch" class="ui-icon-alt"   data-i18n="[placeholder]attr.placeholderSearch;" data-theme="a"/>
</div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/rBu3W/1/)

Comment: you will have to change the image.

Comment: can you help i have the link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `background-image` value with `images/icons-18-black.png` by add this CSS:

```
.ui-icon-searchfield:after
{
    background-image: url(images/icons-18-black.png); //Remember to update this path
}
```

Here is your fiddle with the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/rBu3W/3/